# Jquery Ajax and the use of $.toJSON() function

Tags: jquery

what is the use of $.toJSON() function. it seems that it convert the data in json format.
here is the code snippet

```
data: $.toJSON({ name: $("input[type=text]").val() })
```

without using $.toJSON() function we can supply data manually in josn format like

```
data: { name: $("input[type=text]").val() }
```

it will also work i think. please discuss. thanks

Comment: For reference, the docs for the jquery-json plugin are here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `toJSON` [is not a native jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/?s=toJSON).

Assuming it does the same as [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Converting_objects_into_JSON), it is **not** the same as assigning an object to the `data` option. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (emphasis mine):

> Data to be sent to the server. **It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.** It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

So if you don't pass a string (i.e. the object), the data is converted to a **query string**, not JSON.

To be more precise

```
data: $.toJSON({ name: $("input[type=text]").val() })
```

would result in this URL (assuming GET (`%22` is `"`)):

```
http://some_server.com/?{%22name%22:%22somevalue%22}
```

This would make the value difficult to access I suppose. It makes more sense using this ina POST request.

On the other hand,

```
data: { name: $("input[type=text]").val() }
```

results in

```
http://some_server.com/?name=somevalue
```

---

Maybe important to point out is that in your example

```
{ name: $("input[type=text]").val() }
```

is not "JSON format". It is a JavaScript object literal. JSON is a data exchange format, and although its syntax is similar to JavaScript's object literals, it is something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON-format` and `JSON-object` are two different things!

The `toJSON` (a plugin method) does the following:

> toJSON: Serializes a javascript object, number, string, or array into JSON.

---

1. `data: $.toJSON({ name: $("input[type=text]").val() })` will give you **JSON string**
2. `data: { name: $("input[type=text]").val() }` will give you **javascript object**

Comment: That is for the `$.getJSON` function, not the `$.toJSON` function.

Comment: @EvanMulawski. what about now?